# What web Python interpeter should I use for this case?

Tags: javascript, web-development, html, web

I am making a website to help teach users Python. What service can I use to run custom Python functions (no other libraries)?

For example, the user inputs `down(2)` on my website, this service takes that and see they want to use the down function, and then I can handle that and make an HTML element move down two times.